# How to choose a proper image shape for deep learning in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I have a a model to train in python using keras and my training dataset contains 30 000 images. Those images represents animals for a total of 6 classes.

> My problem is when i come to choose an `image_shape` for the training,
> the images have different shapes so i am not very sure what to do in
> this case. I thought about finding the max/min height and max/min
> width to see what should be a decent shape to choose.

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input, BatchNormalization, UpSampling2D, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger, ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.saving import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ==========================================
# ===============GPU SETUP==================
# ==========================================
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 2, 'CPU': 4})
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(sess)

# ==========================================
# ================VARIABLES=================
# ==========================================
drivePath = "drive/My Drive/"
mainDataPath = drivePath + "donnees/"
DataPath = mainDataPath + "entrainement"
testPath = mainDataPath + "test"
modelsPath = "Model.hdf5"


n_classes = 6 # nombre de classes d'animaux
training_batch_size = 24000  # total 24 000 (4000 par classes d'animaux)
validation_batch_size = 6000  # total 6000 (1000 par classes d'animaux)

image_scale = ????
image_channels = 3  # le nombre de canaux de couleurs (1: pour les images noir et blanc; 3 pour les images en couleurs (rouge vert bleu) )
images_color_mode = "rgb"  # grayscale pour les image noir et blanc; rgb pour les images en couleurs 
image_shape = (image_scale, image_scale, image_channels) # la forme des images d'entrees, ce qui correspond e la couche d'entree du reseau

fit_batch_size = 32 # le nombre d'images entrainees ensemble: un batch
fit_epochs = 50 # Le nombre d'epoques
```

How can i calculate the `maximum height`, `minimum height`, `mean height`, `maximum width`, `minimum width`, `mean width` of my images and choose a proper shape based on those values?

**This is the structure of my data**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the larger the images the better the model performs. That assumes however that the images are of a certain fidelity to begin with. For example if most of your images are say 50 X 50 X 3 blowing them up to sat 250 X 250 X 3 probably won't help your model perform better and on a computational basis will be 25 times more computationally expensive. Probably the best setting would be to set the image size to the mean of the height and width. I have found in general that the image size is not that critical as long as it is reasonable say 200 X 200 X 3 for example. You can do all the work to get the means by reading in all the files sequentially, determine the height and width and take the average. Code for that is shown below:

```
import os
import cv2
train_dir = r'drive\mydrive\donnees\entrainement' # your train directory
test_dir = r'drive\mydrive\donnees\test'          # your test directory
total_height, total_width,total_files= 0,0,0      # initialize counters
for tr_test in [train_dir, test_dir]:             # iterate through train and test directories
    class_list= os.listdir(tr_test)               # get the list of class directories
    for c in class_list:                          # iterate through the class directories
        c_path=os.path.join(tr_test, c)
        f_list=os.listdir(c_path)                 # get the list of files in the class directory
        for f in f_list:                          # iterate through the files
            f_path=os.path.join(c_path, f)
            img=cv2.imread(f_path)                # read in the image
            height, width, channels=img.shape     # get the height and width
            total_height=total_height + height
            total_width=total_width + width
            total_files=total_files +1
average_height=int (total_height/total_files)     # determine average height
average_width= int(total_width/total_files)       # determine average width
print ('Average Height = ', average_height, '   Average Width = ', average_width, '   Total Files = ', total_files)
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick to training these is to realise that you will not be using the images in their native resolution -- instead you will be cropping them to a common size to be able to batch efficiently.

In your case, you should look at something like `https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_with_crop_or_pad` and experiment with what looks sensible, or just what brings the best results. Good luck!